# Bootstrap sticky-top nav-bar is overlapping content when I use smooth scroll

Tags: html, css, nav, sticky, smooth-scrolling

I have tried to fix this error for a few days and no googling or old answers seem to fix the issue.

I have added a sticky-top nav bar that sits within my body (underneath a jumbotron hero image, also within body). I have added in smooth scroll and everything works fine. However, when I click on a link and it scrolls down, it overlaps the beginning of my container with the content.

I have tried adding padding-top and margin to my body as I have seen suggested but it places the padding above the jumbotron (.hero). I have then tried taking my jumbotron and nav out of body and placing them in header, which does fix the issue of the overlap but the nav no longer sticks to the top of the page (which is probably why it fixes the issue!)

There doesn't seem to be any overflow in the css that would cause this.

This is my first attempt at writing code so I've run out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions or reasons as to why this is happening?

I have set this up in a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ahronpeskin/gbmsket1) it seems to have added a white space between my jumbotron and nav bar - and the smooth scroll doesn't work but clicking the links has the same issue.

```
HTML

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarText">
   <!--hero image-->
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid hero">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Jill Peskin Counselling</h1>
      <p>
        Here for you when you need it most
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>

  <!--navbar-->
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jill Peskin Counselling</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#jill">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#training">Training and Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="navbar-text">
        Here for you when you need it most
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>


CSS

body{
    position: relative;
}

/*hero image*/
.hero{
  background: url(Images/zen.jpg) fixed center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
padding: 400px;
text-transform: none;
color:white;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

/*navbar*/

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community, can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle ? So that it can be checked and understood properly.

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing on the fiddle link you just gave.

Comment: @GagandeepSingh - thanks I've deleted and re-added my link! I've copied all my code into jsfiddle. it seems to have added a white space between my jumbotron and nav bar - and the smooth scroll doesn't work but clicking the links has the same issue. (https://jsfiddle.net/ahronpeskin/gbmsket1/)

Comment: Please move the jsfiddle URL into the original post body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of JQuery-Slim use normal minified JQuery.

And do the smooth scrolling with that.

here:

```html
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script> 

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--smooth scroll-->
    <script src="js/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).on('click', 'a.nav-link', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log("CLICKED ANCHOR!");

          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - $(".navbar.sticky-top").height()
          }, 500);
      });
    </script>
```

This basically listens for a click on a.nav-link, prevents default behavior,
calculates the offset from top and subtracts the height of the nav itself

If you have any further questions, please ask

Comment: Thank you @antax  - this solved my issue of that overlap. I have two questions off the back of this. firstly, it has now made my scrollspy slightly off (i had an offset of about 56px) but now I don't know how to add that to the JS. Secondly, moving forward should I always use a minified version? Rather than the slim, I think I used slim because a youtube tutorial said so, but without real justification.

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply, i forgot to add the scrollspy script in their:

```js
        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbarText',offset: 56 })
```

this is just the stuff you added, simply add this.
Scrollspy has nothing todo with smooth scrolling.
yes you should use minified versions.
slim version is also most likely minified, just that it doesn't have all features the full blown library has.

but for .animate() you need the normal minified version not the slim minifed one.

You could also add a data-attribute for the offset (next comment link)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#via-data-attributes

Comment: Thanks @antax - I managed to work out how to add the data-attribute to the body tag that fixed my problem. Good to know about the difference between minified and slim. Why would anyone ever use the slim version? What is the benefit?

Comment: Hey, great!
Stuff's pretty easy once you get the hang of it :)

Slim version's benefit is that it is much smaller than the full version

Have a great day